# Draggable Icons on a Google Map V3 - Set to Draggable=True, but can not drag it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, draggable, google-maps-markers

I have everything working on this Google map V3 on how I would like it except for one last thing. Right now, If you load up the map, the map is able to search for a place and drag an icon from outside the map into the Google map. **However**, once the icon is inside the map, I am not able to drag it. I've search endlessly on where I went wrong on my code.

Below are a few examples of many that I read on:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314698/in-google-maps-v3-how-can-i-get-a-draggable-marker-to-pan-the-map),
[Link2](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html?r=49), [Link3](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/7oWus3T5Ycw), [Link4](http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/drag-from-outside.html) (Link 4 is what i need but could not connect the code after further inspection)

I feel I am very close but I believe I am just not declaring the right variables or not connecting them right. **Below is the code** and here is a [FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4s2y/1/) that can give you a picture of my problem. (Try dragging the icon once and then dragging it again inside the map)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        height: 97%;
    }
    #map-canvas {
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -30%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        }
    #shelf {
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: 5px;
        top: 25px;
        left: 70%;
        height: 98%;
        width: 30%;
        float: right;
    }
    #draggable {z-index:1000000000;}
    #draggable2 {z-index:1000000000;}
    #draggable3 {z-index:1000000000;}
    .ecostation {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border: 1.0px solid #F0F0F0;
        border-radius: 5.0px 5.0px 5.0px 5.0px;
        width: 85%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #wrapper {
        display: table-row;
        border: 1.0px solid rgb(204,204,204);
        border-radius: 5.0px 5.0px 5.0px 5.0px;
    }
    #wrapper div {
        display: table-cell;
        border-radius: 10.0px 10.0px 10.0px 10.0px;
        width: 12.5%;
    }
    #wrapper div img {
        display: block;
        padding: 5.0px;
        margin: 5.0px auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #wrapper div h5, #wrapper div p {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin-top: -10px;
        font-weight: 800;
    }
    .title {
        margin-left: 7%;
        color:  #F0F0F0;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    #target {
    width: 345px;
    }
</style>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#draggable").draggable({helper: 'clone',
                stop: function(e) {
                    var point=new google.maps.Point(e.pageX,e.pageY);
                    var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
                    var icon = $(this).attr('src');
                    placeMarker(ll, icon);
                }
            });
            $("#draggable2").draggable({helper: 'clone',
                stop: function(e) {
                    var point=new google.maps.Point(e.pageX,e.pageY);
                    var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
                    var icon = $(this).attr('src');
                    placeMarker(ll, icon);
                }
            }); 
        });
</script>
<script>
    // This example adds a search box to a map, using the
    // Google Places autocomplete feature. People can enter geographical searches.
    // The search box will return a pick list containing
    // a mix of places and predicted search terms.
        function initialize() {
            var markers = [];
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
                new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
            map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('target');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
    // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            }
    // For each plce, get the icon, place name, and location.
        markers = [];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
            var image = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

    // Create a marker for each place.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }   
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    // [END region_getplaces]
    // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
    // current map's viewport.
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        function placeMarker(location, icon) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location, 
                map: map,
                draggable:true,
                icon: icon                     
            });
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="panel">
        <input id="target" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    </div>
 <div id='shelf'>
    <div class="ecostation">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div>
                <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mobile-development-icons/30/Map_marker.png" id="draggable" title="Estation Trash/Compost" alt="Estation Trash and Compost"/>
                <p>Trash/Compost</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/large-tab-bar-icons/30/Start_flag.png" id="draggable2" title="Estation Trash" alt="Estation Trash"/>
                <p>Trash</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://i1288.photobucket.com/albums/b489/Wallace_Adams/bth_facebook-icon-30x30_zpsb49e1af3.jpg" id="draggable3" title="Estation Recycling" alt="Estation Recycling"/>
                <p>Recycle</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
</html>
```

### end of code

If you guys can let me know that would be great! Also, i noticed that `marker` is declared twice. Is that one of the problems? I tried declaring something else but had no luck.
I also came accross this code but not sure if it is helpful in this situation

```
var overlay;
overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
            overlay.draw = function() {};
            overlay.setMap(map);
```

Possibly thinking it has to do something with this piece of code below?

```
function placeMarker(location, icon) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location, 
            map: map,
            draggable:true,
            icon: icon                     
        });
    }
```

But then again, couldn't figure what was wrong with, am I connecting the variables correctly?

Help would be greatly appreciated, I am very close to finishing what I want to accomplish on this map

Comment: I don't see a map on [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ochoa24/9hp7q/), I see a javascript error "google is not defined".  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4s2y/1/) shows a map (changed the external dependencies).

Comment: @geocodezip for some reason, I can't load the map on the fiddle, but the map does load if you launch it in a browser

Comment: Even in [my version](http://jsfiddle.net/r4s2y/1/) of it?

Comment: @geocodezip oh nice, i didn't see your fiddle, the map loads up. So the problem can be shown clearly now, I can not get the icon to drag inside the map. The icon can be dragged the first time, but when you try to move it a second time, it won't let you. Any ideas of what is wrong?

Comment: Could the icon that was dragged onto the map be on top of the native google.maps.Marker, making it impossible to click on?

Comment: @geocodezip Would it be possible to explain that a bit more? The native markers that are declared right now do not show up until after a search is entered. Possibly, I believe the Google Map is not registering that the icon is being dropped in, thus the map and the marker are not connecting and not allowing it to drag inside the map. Also, in the search script, there is a marker that is declared to drop a marker after a place is searched. I wonder if that marker is conflicting with the custom marker that is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are not using svg images for the icon.  They seem to work on FireFox and Chrome, but not IE